# BizTalk Implementation for webservice interface

Tags: biztalk

I am receiving a flat files with many records.
I need to call a web service.
Request to this web service is each record in flat file.
Web service will be allowing request on by one (not bulk operation).

So I used the

- XML disassemble pipeline in receive location
- then map the record to web service request
- call web service
- Receive response.

If I receive 500 record 500 orchestration instances I can see in the admin console. Is this the right way to do this?

Please advice? Is it will impact the performance?

I am no getting errors. I'm confused about the approach ....seeing many orchestration instances.

Comment: You could rewrite the solution to let a single orchestration loop each row and call the web service 500 times.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a working solution.

You must have specified the flat file so that it is doing the disassembling by telling it to expect one record.

It all depends on how many records you are expecting and what else is going through BizTalk at the time to know if there is any performance impact, but if it is just 500 instances, usually I wouldn't be too worried if the BizTalk server is not showing any throttling.

So unless you are experiencing issues, your solution is fine.

Comment: if it 5000 also its working...for 5000 record any chance of throttling or any performace issues?

Comment: Hi bigB.  BizTalk is very good at handling lots of things in parallel. You will have to monitor your server and see how it goes.  It all depends on your environment setup as to it's capacity and the throttling settings.

Answer (score 0):

It could impact the performance, but is hard to say without knowing the message payload and the specifics of your situation.

If you question is "is this scalable beyond my initial test?" then consider setting up a host with throttling.

Using the Biztalk Administration Console create a new host and in the Settings section of the host, use the "Rate Based Throttling" options to restrict how many messages are processed in a given period if this is your performance concern.

Set the send port send handler to your web service to use this host instance.